# CodeIgniter loading one page after another is randomly long

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am encountering a strange problem with CodeIgniter.

When I am calling one page then another with a 1-second gap between each call the pages both loads at approximatively 0.2 second each.

But if I wait five seconds after the call of the first page the second page will take 5 seconds to load despite the fact that the benchmark module of CI says that the page loaded in 0.4 second.

The problem is present in Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer but not in Google Chrome.

Edit : Forgot to mention that I have a hook which verifies if the user is connected or not.

Comment: sounds like a hosting problem, other than a ci related problem - because if CI says it takes 0.4s to render the page, it means it took only 0.4s ;) maybe do you have some external JS Files (some cdn's or something like that?)

Comment: All my JS and CSS files are local. Yesterday I also forgot to mention that I also use Smarty. Does CodeIgniter also count the template compilation time in his benchmark module ?